# How do I use javascript to repeatedly submit a form?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

How can I submit a form every 5 seconds using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout("$('#form').submit()",5000);
```

without jQuery...

```
setTimeout("document.forms['yourform'].submit();",5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but you can use [`setTimeout()`<sup>docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) or [`setInterval()`<sup>docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) methods.

Keep in mind though that when you submit a form you submit it to a url, and you go to that url (*unless you use ajax*). If your target page is the same as the source page, then the page is reloaded so your script starts from scratch ..

the following code would submit the form 5 seconds after its execution
*in a page that reloads it would execute again so it would effectively submit every 5 secs*

```
setTimeout(function(){
              document.getElementById('formID').submit();
            }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will only fire once, setInterval will fire every x milliseconds